# Different meta tags for each page

Tags: php, html, meta

I have a single header called on different pages through PHP. But in order to be detected for SEO, I have to include separate meta tags and description for each page.

I am using following PHP code for this:

```
<?php
$cur_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 

         if($cur_url == "https://www.example.com/" || $cur_url == "https://example.com/"){

             ?>
              <body id="main-homepage" class="homepage-travels">
                <meta >  


             <?php
         }
         else if($cur_url == "https://example.com/one-travel-packages" || $cur_url == "https://example.com/one-travel"){

         }
         else{
             ?>
              <body id="main-homepage">
             <?php
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: Then share code.

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing? Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Ok so first you have to decide what meta information you need for each page. Then you have to provide that information for each page which could be set in a array on each page or from a database. Then you have to grab the info and insert the values into the correct locations.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer following code for dynamic meta tags according to pages..

following is the codeigniter framework code.. **just grasp the logic of code**

put this logic in header..

```
<?php

$current_url = $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$pg_id = $this->uri->segment(1);

switch ($pg_id) {
    case 'about-us':
        $where="`page_url` LIKE '%about-us%' ";
        $qry="SELECT * FROM `ci_site_meta` WHERE `is_active` ='1' AND ".$where."";
        $page_details = $this -> home -> customQuery($qry);
        break;

    case 'contact-us':
        $where="`page_url` LIKE '%contact-us%' ";
        $qry="SELECT * FROM `ci_site_meta` WHERE `is_active` ='1' AND ".$where."";
        $page_details = $this -> home -> customQuery($qry);
        break;
    ....
    ....    
}
?>
<?php if(!empty($page_details)){ ?>  

            <title><?php echo $page_details[0]->title; ?></title>
            <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page_details[0]->meta_description; ?>" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $page_details[0]->meta_keywords; ?>" />
            ....
            ....
<?php }else{ ?>

            <!-- place all default meta tags -->

<?php } ?>
```

Modify above code as per your requirement..